# There are too many differences in Java performance between operating systems

Tags: java, performance, parsing, apache-poi

I tested the program I developed.

However, there is a significant difference in performance for each operating system of Java.

I've been trying to find the cause all day, but haven't found it.

The logic I developed is as follows:

1. A user uploads an excel in a browser.
2. Read excel using poi library.
3. Converts the read string data into an object through parsing.
4. Save the converted object to Cassandra database.

> In the demo source, only the part that parses the data is attached at the bottom. 
> The data parsing logic also has a serious performance difference.

The environment configuration is as follows.

1. SpringBoot-2.2.2.Release
2. JVMOptions is -Xms16g -Xmx16g
3. Cassandra-3.11.7
4. OpenJDK1.8

I ran 3 tests, and the results are:

### Test 1

1. SpringBoot-2.2.2.Release
2. JVMOptions is -Xms16g -Xmx16g
3. Cassandra-3.11.7
4. OpenJDK1.8

- Windows OS

  - poi excel read: 2 seconds
  - Data parsing: 42 seconds
  - Database save: 31 seconds
- Linux OS

  - poi excel read: 2 seconds
  - Data parsing: 4 seconds
  - Database save: 5 seconds

### Test 2 (Save logic removed)

1. SpringBoot-2.2.2.Release
2. JVMOptions is -Xms16g -Xmx16g
3. Cassandra-3.11.7
4. OpenJDK1.8

- Windows OS

  - poi excel read: 2 seconds
  - Data parsing: 40 seconds
- Linux OS

  - poi excel read: 1 seconds
  - Data parsing: 6 seconds

### Test 3

> This test was conducted because it was determined that there was a performance degradation in the process of parsing data.

1. JVMOptions is -Xms16g -Xmx16g
2. OpenJDK1.8

- Windows OS

  - poi excel read: 2 seconds
  - Data parsing: 2 seconds
- Linux OS

  - poi excel read: 2 seconds
  - Data parsing: 1 seconds

However, the results were unexpected.
By removing all previously developed logic and performing data parsing, the speed has been greatly increased.

I am doing it through a simple restAPI request in the browser.

I don't know which point to do cause analysis. Help.

[Excel sample data to parse DOWNLOAD](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n-S6w32FhJ4QUO9MIUwWotQFxHunj9Yr/view?usp=sharing)

```java
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class DemoApplication {

    public static final List<String> TABLE_USERNOUN_EXCEL_FIELD = Arrays.asList("keyword", "separation", "foreign");
    public static final List<String> TITLE_USERNOUN_EXCEL_FIELD = Arrays.asList("검색어", "분리정보", "외래어");


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Long start = new Date().getTime();
            List<Map<String, Object>> data = readFileData();
            Long end = new Date().getTime();
            System.out.println(data.toString());
            System.out.println("finish time : " +(end-start)/1000+ "seconds");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> readFileData() throws IOException {
        List<String> tableColumns = TABLE_USERNOUN_EXCEL_FIELD;
        List<String> columnNames = TITLE_USERNOUN_EXCEL_FIELD;
        List<Map<String, Object>> contents = new ArrayList(); // contents array
        List<Integer> requiredList = Arrays.asList(0,1);

        Path targetLocation = Paths.get("D:","usernoun_dic_10000.xlsx");
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(targetLocation.toString()));
        SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream));

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getXSSFWorkbook().getSheetAt(0);
        int rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        if (rows<2){
            workbook.close();
            inputStream.close();

            return contents;
        }

        Row checkRow = sheet.getRow(0);
        int cellCnt = checkRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        if (cellCnt<columnNames.size()){
            workbook.close();
            inputStream.close();

            return contents;
        }else if (cellCnt>columnNames.size()){
            Object check = getCellValue(checkRow.getCell(tableColumns.size()));

            if (check!=null){
                if (!check.toString().equals("")){
                    workbook.close();
                    inputStream.close();

                    return contents;
                }
            }
        }else{
            for (int i=0; i<cellCnt; i++){
                Object cellVal = getCellValue(checkRow.getCell(i));
                String columnName = "";

                if (cellVal!=null){
                    columnName = cellVal.toString();
                }

                if (columnName.equals("")||!columnName.equals(columnNames.get(i))){
                    workbook.close();
                    inputStream.close();

                    return contents;
                }
            }
        }

        sheet.removeRow(checkRow);
        List<String> finalTableColumns = tableColumns;
        List<Integer> finalRequiredList = requiredList;

        sheet.forEach(row -> {
            Map<String, Object> content = new HashMap<>(); //contents object
            AtomicReference<Boolean> skip = new AtomicReference<>(false);

            row.forEach(cell -> {
                int cellIdx = cell.getColumnIndex();
                if (cellIdx< finalTableColumns.size()){
                    Object value = getCellValue(cell);

                    boolean require = finalRequiredList.stream().anyMatch(integer -> integer==cellIdx);

                    if (require){
                        if (value!=null){
                            if (value.toString().equals("")){
                                skip.set(true);
                            }
                        }else{
                            skip.set(true);
                        }
                    }

                    content.put(finalTableColumns.get(content.size()), value);
                }
            });

            if (!skip.get()){
                contents.add(content);
            }
        });

        workbook.close();
        inputStream.close();
        return contents;
    }

    public static Object getCellValue(Cell cell) {

        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case BLANK: //Null exception
                return "";
            case ERROR:
                return cell.getErrorCellValue();
            case STRING:
                return cell.getStringCellValue();
            case BOOLEAN:
                return cell.getBooleanCellValue();
            case NUMERIC:
                return cell.getNumericCellValue();
            case FORMULA:
                return cell.getCellFormula();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe right time to learn using [profiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html) ?

Comment: It is not clear if your question is: How to better profile your code, or: What's wrong in your code which is killing performance. For the first one, learn how to use a profiler. For the second question, one (of several tips to enhance performance) is: avoid using         sheet.removeRow(checkRow); and find another way to implement your code without removeRow.

Comment: Virus Checker on Windows doing silly things and slowing it all down?

Comment: @Victor Polo De Gyves Montero, Thank you. i solved it using a profiler.